# SQL Server insert update from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have 2 tables Winner and player , containing standard information(last name,first name,ID ...) plus two boolean columns Validity and WinnerState(default to 0).

what i want to do is create a SQL Server procedure that will randomly select one record from the Players Table and then insert it into Winner Table and update in the same time the WinnerState column of the record selected in the player Table.

the Winner table contain a foreign key to the Player, to keep trace of this player selected.

i've already tried one procedure but it updates this column for all the player Table:

```
create procedure selectUpdate
    As
    insert into Winner (Fname,Lname,Adress,City,Tel,Player_ID) from
    select TOP 1 (Fname,Lname,Adress,City,Tel,ID) from Player order by NEWID()
    Update Player
    SET WinnerState=1
```

HOw can i make it update only the record selected randomly? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that ID is an INT and the primary key of the Player table:

```
DECLARE @id INT

SELECT TOP 1 @id = ID FROM Player ORDER BY NEWID()

insert into Winner (Fname,Lname,Adress,City,Tel,Player_ID) from
select Fname,Lname,Adress,City,Tel,ID from Player WHERE ID = @id

Update Player
SET WinnerState=1 WHERE ID = @id
```

Comment: and that solves it all thank you ...didn't think about declaring a temporary  Value to transit from the two tables Excellent Job.

Answer (score 3):

You can do all in one statement:

```
create procedure selectUpdate
as
begin
    set nocount on

    ;with p as (
       select top 1 Fname,Lname,Adress,City,Tel,ID,WinnerState
       from Player
       where WinnerState = 0 -- this is necessary I assume
       order by checksum(NEWID())
    )
    update p
    set WinnerState = 1
    output
        inserted.Fname,
        inserted.Lname,
        inserted.Adress,
        inserted.City,
        inserted.Tel,
        inserted.ID into Winner (Fname,Lname,Adress,City,Tel,Player_ID)
end
```